# eclipse C compiler does not recognize // in line comments

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Ok, this is the problem: I use yoxos to keep my eclipse up to date: and the other day I was upgraded to Mars .2 my C compiler (GCC tool Chain) stopped accepting '//' as comment lines, I checked other projects which had no errors, now have the same error:

Description...................Resource..Path............................Location...Type
expected expression before '/' token    demo.c  /demo1/Host    line 98  C/C++ Problem

```
(93)       /* STOP FLYING! */
(94)    
(95)    printf("\n END OF THE LINE******************************** %4d \n", count );
(96)    PLatLon( dlat, dlon );
(97)    /* print"</body></html>"; */
(98)    // now return
(99)    return(1);}
```

I there a freaken switch somewhere that got flipped/set wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is from my console:

> gcc
>   -I"/mnt/MyData/home/harrison/NexGen/Code-Base/NAV/Server/demo1/NAV_Includes"
>   -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fPIC -lm -fmessage-length=0 -ansi -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"Host/demo.d" -MT"Host/demo.o" -o "Host/demo.o" "../Host/demo.c

1. List item: Project --> Properties --> C/C++ Build --> Settings find the Tool Settings tab and change the GCC C Compiler dialect --> Language Standard. You need c99.
2. List item: Project --> Properties --> C/C++ Build --> Settings find the Tool Settings tab -> Miscellaneous *uncheck* Support ANSI programs

Now my // errors are gone!